# Is there a better way to consume data from event hubs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-eventhub

I am new to event hub and tried to implement a consumer like the following

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal#receive-events-from-the-event-hub

But I have some questions:

1 - I used a service background, but when I create a delay (await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))) for the task, if I receive a batch while the task is about to close, I get a error trying to consume cause the processor is stopped in the middle of consuming, there's a better approach to implement this?

2 - If I have more than a event hub to consume, I'll need to create another service background doing the same thing but for a diferent hub?

Comment: Dont close the connection and dont do any Task.Delay. Just continuously process the incomming events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `@ Magnus` for the comments.

When consuming data from Event Hubs, you need to follow the below.

- Instead of using a fixed delay with `Task.Delay`, you can use a long-polling approach to consume events.
- This involves setting a longer timeout when receiving events from the Event Hub.
- You can set the `ReceiveTimeout` property to a larger value so that the receive operation waits for events for a longer period before timing out.

You can avoid the issue of closing the processor while events are still being consumed.

- Instead of relying on the service background's task to consume events, `you can create a separate task` or `thread dedicated to event processing`. This helps to decouple the event consumption logic from the service background and ensures that events are continuously processed even if the service background task is paused or stopped for some reason.
- Based on the programming language using, there will be higher-level frameworks available that provide abstractions for consuming events from Event Hubs. And these frameworks often handle the complexities of `managing connections, retries, and event processing`, allowing you to focus on the business logic.

In .NET, you can consider using the [Azure Event Hubs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-sdk) or [Azure Functions Event Hubs trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp), which provides easy way of  event consumption.

> For your question, you can use a single Event Processor Host instance to consume events from multiple Event Hubs.

You can specify the name of the Event Hub in the [constructor of the EventProcessorHost class](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host.md).

For more information refer to [MSDoc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples).